Prettier is removing typescript generic annotation from react class component
I'm trying to make an ErrorBoundary using a class component like this
class ErrorBoundary extends Component<ErrorBoundaryProps,ErrorBoundaryState>

But every time I format it with prettier, the part <ErrorBoundaryProps,ErrorBoundaryState> disappears, I'm not sure if it's prettier or eslint.
Here's my .eslintrc.json
{
  "extends": [
    "next/core-web-vitals",
    "plugin:storybook/recommended"
  ],
  "plugins": ["simple-import-sort"],
  "rules": {
    "simple-import-sort/imports": "error",
    "simple-import-sort/exports": "error"
  },
  "parserOptions": {
    "sourceType": "module",
    "ecmaVersion": "latest"
  }
}


Upgrading to the latest version(version 3.3.3) solved my issue.

Works for me too! Thanks

This is not working for me. Still removing generics in 3.3.3

for me, I was in (version 3.3.3) so downgrading to the prior version 3.3.2)solved my issue. I dont know why this happens as previous comment says 3.3.3 fixes his problem.

this worked for me

Same here. I'm surprised Prettier would do something like that, it's usually pretty stable…

Install Necessary Plugins:
Make sure you have the required ESLint and Prettier plugins installed:
npm install --save-dev eslint prettier eslint-plugin-prettier eslint-config-prettier @typescript-eslint/parser @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin

Disable ESLint Formatting:
You can configure ESLint to not format certain aspects. Add the following rule to your .eslintrc.json to prevent ESLint from interfering with TypeScript generics:
"rules": {
  "react/jsx-filename-extension": "off",
  "react/prop-types": "off",
  "typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any": "off"
}

Use the Correct Parser:
Ensure you're using the TypeScript parser for ESLint. Your .eslintrc.json should include:
"parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
"extends": [
  "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
  "next/core-web-vitals",
  "plugin:storybook/recommended"
]

Configure Prettier and ESLint to Work Together:
Add the following to your .eslintrc.json to integrate Prettier with ESLint:
"extends": [
  "plugin:prettier/recommended"
]

